# Trying to Open Jupyter Notebook from Terminal constantly getting error of zsh: command not found: jupyter: Python Version: 2.7.16

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, zsh

I updated my Mac OS from High Sierra to Catalina

I asked this question before, someone suggested me this syntax: python3 -m pip install jupyter

When I tried this syntax it worked for the 1st time. After then when I completed my work and saved my file and exited Jupyter Notebook from the terminal.

When I tried to open Jupyter Notebook from my Mac Terminal the 2nd time by just writing `% jupyter notebook` onto the terminal, it gave me an error: `zsh: command not found: jupyter`

Tried all the different approaches online, but I am not able to fix this issue.

Can anyone guide me on how I can fix this problem ?

Comment: Did you run the command using `sudo`?

Comment: To be honest I have used this command sudo -h pip install -U Pillow. But this one didn't worked. Can you let me know what type of sudo command should I use ?

Comment: did you install it in a virtual environment?

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe  I don't know. Do you know how I can check whether it is installed in a virtual environment ?

Comment: @Parag if you don't know then you probably didn't do it in a virtual environment what does your $PATH variable look like?

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe I didn't understand how to find the path so I used echo $PATH and it gave me this result.  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

Comment: @Parag that's exactly how you do it if you type `pip3 freeze` do you see `jupyter` installed? It should look like `jupyter==1.0.0`. Also type `which python3` and make sure its using a `usr/local/bin` python as well

Comment: I type pip3 freeze the command got executed but it didn't showed me anything regarding jupyter installed. I entered second syntax and it gave me this output /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 @MatthewBarlowe

Comment: ok then try `pip3 install jupyter` and then try to run `jupyter notebook` that should work it looks like its not installed for some reason even though you pip installed it earlier

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe Yes it worked and I am able to access the jupyter notebook from my terminal directly.  Can I know what exactly was wrong and Do you think this problem might occur again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pip3 install jupyter` and then you should be able to run `jupyter notebook` form the terminal. As far as what caused the issue its hard to say it could be a variety of issues especially with the OSX update. I'm guessing though that it stems from the initial install by `python3 -m pip install jupyter`. I always install using `pip` or `pip3` as I said above which will install it globally

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the taking the time and helping me Mr. Matthew. I had one more question. Do you know how I can update my Python version 2.7 to Version 3.0 from the Terminal itself ? As when I was trying different solutions from online and was executing the syntax. The Terminal was giving me an output that it won't be able to support Python and it will be till Jan 2020 and I have to update it from bash to zhrc something like this.

Comment: Do not touch the python 2.7 version on your system that is installed my Mac and used by your OS continue to use `python3` to run the scripts you need in python 3. and If you could accept my answer i would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Suggestion for installing python3. First than anything else, as stated above, it's better to leave the python version of the system at it is because you could crash your computer. That's why you would need to install your own version of python 2 and 3. To do that, basically just install homebrew and with homebrew you'll be able to install python 2 and 3. You could google something like "mac install python3" or python 2 as well. As an extra, to set up your virtual enviroment you could also google something similar. [Link] https://programwithus.com/learn-to-code/install-python3-mac/

Answer (score 0):

Execute `pip3 show jupyter`. This will show you where pip has installed Jupyter. Afterwards, you can execute `jupyter notebook` from that directory.

Comment: When I executed the 1st syntax. It gave me this error zsh: command not found: pip

Answer (score 0):

No need to install anything or copy paste any code. Simply run the below code in your terminal after changing the user name "sudhanshukumar" to your Mac user name

```
/Users/sudhanshukumar/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command
```